# Display "Generating..." text while mPDF generates file

Tags: php, mpdf

Is there anyway to display some text, indicating that the mPDF script is still working on generating the PDF?

I tried to do a simple Echo before i run the script, but it seems like it doesnt show, or mPDF clears it out or something.

Comment: You'll have to do it asynchronously, via AJAX...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to enable mPDF progress bars! inside `/mpdf/config.php`

```
$this->progressBar = 1;// Shows progress-bars whilst generating file 0 off, 1 simple, 2 advanced
```